# How to access GWT's JsInterop exported types from browser console?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I'm running a GWT application and I want to test something quickly with JsInterop.

Specifically, I exported an `enum`:

```
package com.mypackage.test

@JsType
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C;
}
```

And I wanna check if I can access it properly before writing any code.

Docs show things like this:

```
var aClass = new com.gwt.example.MyClass('World');
```

But `com` is not defined in `Window`. So how can I access JsInterop from console to test things before writing code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to pass the `-generateJsInteropExports` flag to the compiler (and to Super Dev Mode)? Without it, GWT will not export types, since that increases output size.

Also, that package doesn't look like the usual structure you expect to see in a GWT project (i.e. a `client` somewhere in there, corresponding to your GWT module) - did you remember to reference this package from your .gwt.xml file?

It is also possible that this should be `public` - the JsInterop code defaults to not showing non-visible members (since they aren't public, so aren't assumed to be consumed elsewhere). I'm not sure if this applies to types, or just members.

---

Finally, be aware that marking a Java `enum` with JsType doesn't magically make them make sense in JS - there will be a MyEnum type at the specified package, and each of those static members will be present, but they will be opaque JS objects, not strings or something else you can easily interact with, unless you also add other jsinterop annotations on the methods in that class. J2CL supports a `@JsEnum` which will turn them all into numeric constants automatically though, but this hasn't yet been ported to GWT2.

Comment: Having the same issue. What do you mean with referencing the package from your .gwt.xml file? Could you please give an example how that looks?

Comment: Referencing the package is usually just a matter of putting your `.gwt.xml` file in the same directory as the `client` package, but if you also have other translatable sources (say, a `shared` package parallel to both the module file and client package), then you would add a `<source path="shared" />` line to your .gwt.xml file to indicate that there is another package relative to the module file which should be considered for compilation.