# GWT jsinterop java exporting is not working

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I'm working with GWT and am trying to export a java class to be used in javascript in my HTML. This is the java class I want to export to javascript using jsinterop.

```
package com.example.client;

import jsinterop.annotations.*;

@JsType(isNative = false, namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
public class Foo {

  public int x;
  public int y;

  public int sum() {
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

And this is my javascript in my HTML

```
<script>
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.x = 40;
    foo.y = 2;
    foo.sum(); 
</script>
```

I am already using the -generateJsInteropExports flag in the compiler arguments and run configurations. 
However, I still get this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Foo is not defined
at MyProgramName.html: 59 (the line where i try to instantiate it)

Also, using the default namespace doesn't work either. When I use:

```
var foo = new com.example.client.Foo();
```

I get the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access GWT's JsInterop exported types from browser console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594322/how-to-access-gwts-jsinterop-exported-types-from-browser-console)

Comment: Having the same issue, but with "com is not defined". Also using -generateJsInteropExports flag.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to pass the -generateJsInteropExports flag to the compiler (and to Super Dev Mode)? Without it, GWT will not export types, since that increases output size.

(This question looks like a simpler version of [How to access GWT's JsInterop exported types from browser console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594322/how-to-access-gwts-jsinterop-exported-types-from-browser-console))

Answer (score 0):

Remember that GWT code starts asynchronously (unless you use a custom linker), so it might just be that you're trying to use the object before it's defined.

As a test, try putting your JS code inside an`setTimeout`.

The real fix would be to either use a custom linker, or setup a callback that you'll call from GWT's `onModuleLoad`.